# How to make my image visible by time counter?

Tags: java, android, time

I want to make simple animation using multi-images on android studio
i have 3 images (img1,img2,img3)
and i want img1 visible firstly then after half second img1 invisible and img2 visible,then after half second img2 invisible and img3 visible,then after half second img3 invisible and img1 visible, so return to the first image like circle 
1>2>3>1>2>3>1>2>3 to unlimited time, so how can i do that, please

Answer (score 0):

```
class ImageAnimation {

    Activity activity;
    android.os.Handler handler;
    ImageView[] images = new ImageView[3];//three images array
    int current = 0;//current image iterator


    public ImageAnimation(Activity activity) {

            handler = new android.os.Handler();


            images[0] = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.you_image1_id);
            images[1] = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.you_image2_id);
            images[2] = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.you_image3_id);

            current = 0;


    }

    public void animateImages() {


            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {



                    //loop for all images and animate it
                    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

                            if (i!=current)
                                    images[i].animate().alpha(1);//show
                            else
                                    images[i].animate().alpha(0);//hide
                    }

                        if (current<images.length)
                            current++;
                        else
                            current=0;//again first one


                        //recurring using the same method - infinite loop
                        animateImages();

                    }
            }, 500); //half a second

    }
};
```